# How to Translate Backend Error Messages, Including Validation Messages, for Multilingual Frontend Display in NestJS and Next.js?

Tags: node.js, next.js, nestjs, nest, i18next

I'm building a web application with a NestJS backend and a Next.js frontend. For localization and translation, I'm using the "next-i18next" library on the frontend, and for validation and error handling, I'm using NestJS's class-validator and other error messages.

Example errors:  `username must be a string`, `username should not be empty`, `username must be longer than or equal to 10 characters`

My backend currently provides error messages, including validation error messages, in a single language. On the frontend, I want to display these error messages in multiple languages to provide a better user experience.

Specifically, I'm using class-validator for validation and need to translate these validation error messages. Additionally, I want to handle translation for other error messages generated by my backend.

How can I efficiently translate these error messages on the frontend while keeping the backend error handling intact? What's the best approach to handle error messages, including validation errors, in different languages between NestJS (backend) and Next.js (frontend) when using "next-i18next" for localization?

I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to implement this solution effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, here is how I would do custom messages for NestJs validations using class-validator.

```
// Your validation class. Note that we are sending a METHOD as the message
export class PostEntryDto {
  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Api Key' })
  @IsString({ message: stringValidationMessage })
  readonly apiKey: string;
}
```

```
export const stringValidationMessage = (args: ValidationArguments): string => {
  return `${capitalize(args.property)} must be a string`; // Use i18n in here to make things smoother for you.
};
```

The only thing to remember here is to always send the function inside the @IsXXXX() with the message key.

Check out the `ValidationArguments` type, you have a few more things you could extract there like the `value` for example to use in your custom message.

For any other places, you would simply inject your i18n strings straight into the error I assume. I would not mix things with backend and client side.

Hope this helps!